# Bitmap Received from socket not update Imageview untill socket close

Tags: android, sockets, bitmap, imageview, serversocket

i want to receive continuously bitmap from socket and update my imageview from new buffer image but imageview not update untill socket close which i close socket then incomming image will update where is Client sided code

```
public void get(){

                try {
                    clientSocket = new Socket(SERVERIP,SERVERPORT);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextview.setText("Connected to server");
                        }
                    });
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {



                                 DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                                 DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                                dout.writeInt(-1001);
                                while(true) {
                                 if(dIn.readInt()==(-1002)){
                                     Log.d(":::::::Attempt for data", ":::::::::::::::::");

                                     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                                     int length = 1;                    // read length of incoming message

                                     byte[] message = new byte[dIn.readInt()];
                                     Log.d(":::Comming Size::",String.valueOf(message.length));

                                         dIn.readFully(message);
                                         baos.write(message, 0, message.length);


                                     Log.d("Stuck", ":::::::::::::: 11111111 "+ String.valueOf(length));

                                     byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
                                     Log.d("Stuck", ":::::::::::::: 22222222 "+ String.valueOf(length));


                                     breceived = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                                     Log.d("Stuck", ":::::::::::::: 33333333 "+ String.valueOf(length));


                                     img.setImageBitmap(breceived);
                                     Log.d("Stuck", ":::::::::::::: 444444444 "+ String.valueOf(length));


                                     // Execute the Runnable in 2 seconds
                                     //handler.postDelayed(t, 2000);
                                     dout.writeInt(-1001);

                                 }else{
                                     Log.d(":::Else Data:::","!!!!!!!!!!!");
                                 }

                                    if(!clientSocket.isConnected()){
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }
                                clientSocket.close();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke the notifyDataSetChanged() method on the function where you get the image.

Comment: Thank Dear for you Response on my question can you please elaborate some details where i need to invoked sorry am not expert so need some guidline i want to update `img.setImageBitmap(breceived);` here i update image which not show me untill socket close so where i need to invoke method ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was the problem of threading. I need to run socket in a background thread and send view to main thread when needed.